# Cartthrob -Stuck with adding additional info to order channel before checkout

Tags: cartthrob

I am sorry to ask again here, but facing a deadline and I am at the beginning of panic. And this is my first site with Cartthrob.
I cannot get my head behind how to add additional info at an order before checkout.

What I want:
The customers might choose another delivery address. When so, they pay no shipping costs.

Solution:
Let them add the information to a field in the order channel, on submit return segment_3 = delevery or = pick-up. Set in the checkout form this conditional:

```
{if segment_3 == "pickup"}
    {set_shipping_plugin value="single_flat_rate"}
{if:else}
    {set_shipping_plugin value="by_quantity_threshold"}
{/if}
```

I made in the order channel a new field, called nieuw_bezorgadres.
I pull information from a Profile:edit channel, showing the addresses as options, code like this:

```
<select name="nieuw_bezorgadres">
{exp:channel:entries channel="member_profiles" category="8"}
<option value="{member_company} {member_address} {member_city} {member_country}">{member_company} {member_address} {member_city} {member_country}</option>
{/exp:channel:entries}
</select>
```

Problem:
But how can I save the information in the order channel for the current transaction?

Thanks a lot for looking at this, it must be simple, that is why I run in circles.....

Comment: I don't understand what you mean in the what I want part "The customers might choose another delivery address. When so, they pay no shipping costs."

Do you mean any other address? Or a certain address? This doesn't make sense to me. You are NOT talking about something like a pick-up option, right?

Comment: This is the wish of the client. He sells to consumers as well as shop-owners. A consumer may wish to have the purchase delivered at a shop. And pick it up there. So, yes, a pick-up address, wih no shipping costs. I must present a list of pick-up addresses, the customer chooses one, these data must be stored in the order channel as additional info in the chart.

Comment: What is happening when you put an order through? I take it nothing is being saved? Have you tested with a plain text input to see if the select is the issue? Finally, I take it the select is in a checkout_form and not an update_cart_form? There are different methods for both. http://cartthrob.com/docs/tutorials/adding_custom_data_to_purchased_items_and_orders/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your Select is inside the checkout_form tag like this:

```
{exp:cartthrob:checkout_form}
    <select name="nieuw_bezorgadres">
        {exp:channel:entries channel="member_profiles" category="8"}
            <option value="{member_company} {member_address} {member_city} {member_country}">{member_company} {member_address} {member_city} {member_country}</option>
        {/exp:channel:entries}
    </select>
{/exp:cartthrob:checkout_form}
```

Then, try renaming the select field to `name="custom_data[nieuw_bezorgadres]"`. I used that for custom order data on a much earlier CartThrob site... not sure if it will work with your version. To print out the variable in the template or the email use `{custom_data:nieuw_bezorgadres}`.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer gave me more insight in how Cartthrob works, that helped me later also.